# Joomla extension development: How to get global params when retrieiving articles from the database?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0, joomla-module

In my extension, I've retrieved articles from the `content` table like this:

```
.......
.......
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('id, catid, title, introtext, attribs);
$query->from('#__content');
$query->where('catid="'.$cid.'"');
$query->where('state="1"');
.......
.......
```

Here I can retrieve `attribs` data for each article being retrieved.

Is there an easy way to retrieve article params from the global settings (is there some sort of static function in Joomla?) or do I need to manually retrieve the `params` from the `extensions` table?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use the [JComponentHelper](http://docs.joomla.org/API17%3aJComponentHelper) class to get the params of the component.

```
<?php

jimport( 'joomla.application.component.helper' );

$com_content_params = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_content');
```

To get the articles I wouldn't write the query myself as you do, but use the relevant JModel (JModelLegacy in Joomla 3) instance instead.

Something that would look like:

```
<?php

$model = JModel::getInstance('Articles', 'ContentModel');
$model->setState('filter.category_id', (int)$cid);
$articles = $model->getList();
```

Don't know if that specific code will work, but you certainly can do some research on Google about that. The spirit is there: use the classes provided by Joomla instead of pulling stuff directly from the DB. You'll gain in maintainability and code quality.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. I'm now redoing my extension by using `JModelLegacy` and it seems to work fine. But I am unable to figure out how the ordering works. I tried something like this: `$model->setState('list.ordering', 'a.publish_up');` but it does not seem to have any effect on the output. Is there something else I have to do in order to get the ordering working?

Comment: ``publish_up`` is set to 0 by default, try ``created_date``.

Comment: No I tried few different options such as `title, hits, etc` but none of them seem to work. `print_r($model->getItems());` outputs an array like this: `Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 12 [title] => Test [alias] => test [introtext] => testtest [checked_out] => 0 [checked_out_time] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 [catid] => 2 [created] => 2014-02-02 00:00:01.................` Still can't figure out why the ordering does not work. Any idea?